# Can Polynomial-sized Neural Network Approximate every (real-valued) function?

Tags: functional-analysis, machine-learning, neural-networks

I know universal approximation theorem says that neural network can approximate every function to arbitrary precision, however it does not bound the size of the neural network. It seems that a more useful theorem would be “what kind of functions can be approximated by polynomial-sized neural networks”. I did some literature search and found Theorem 1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.1141.pdf, which says that every function can be implemented in polynomial time can be **expressed** by a poly-sized neural network. However, it seems that this theorem is restricted to boolean inputs. I'm wondering if it's also true that for every real-valued function that can be evaluated in polynomial time, we can always construct a corresponding neural network of polynomial-size to approximate it (with arbitrary precision)?

Really appreciate if someone can point out some relevant literature for this question.

Comment: On the one hand, this will depend on the activation function. Kn the other hand, it will depend on what exactly you mean by stating that "the function can be implemented in polynomial time". For instance, you can implement discontinuous functions using a programming language (e.g., the sign function). You will not be able to **uniformly** approximate such a function by networks with a continuous activation function. Also, with respect to which quantity should the size of the NN be polynomial? The approximation accuracy or the polynomial bounding the "implementation complexity"?